# IBAction's action scope in making a calculator app

Tags: swift

Why, after I removed action of **func digit** in **Touch Up Inside** in **π**(see picture 1), but when we go to see the action scope of **digit**, you can still see that **digit** contain **π**(see picture 2)?

I mean, why when I touch π, the **func digit** still works.

picture 1:

[image]

picture 2:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can see your button having the text pi in the storyboard, then that means it is but default set to that, and it will be that unless you change it.

To test if I'm right, just try setting the line to something like this:

```
if sender.currentTitle == "5" {
```

Your storyboard should still show it as pi, but when you run it, the func will not be executed and the button will still show pi, because it has been disconnected.

It showing up as pi has nothing do with your func.

In terms of the second part, the only way the digit func will work when you touch pi is if there is a connection between them. I would suggest carefully look through your button's outlets.

Comment: Sorry, you might misunderstand what I mean. I just want remove π out of func digit, and how can I do it?

Comment: Thank you, I figure it out, it overlaps with a button.